# Linux apache set custom launch page Virtualhosts

Tags: apache-httpd, dns

I set up DNS and virtualhosts on my Linux system but when surfing to ex: www.vb1.be it shows the correct directory (home/vb1/) and their subdirectories. I know this is because the main html file that should be loaded isn't named index.html but homepage.html. So how can I set this homepage.html to launch every time someone surfs to www.vb1.be?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/vb1.be
    ServerName vb1.be
    ServerAlias www.vb1.be
    ErrorLog logs/vb1.be-error_log
    CustomLog logs/vb1.be-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DirectoryIndex` directive:

> The `DirectoryIndex` directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client  requests an index of the directory by specifying a `/` at the end of the directory name. Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be given, in which case the server will return the first one that it finds. If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set, the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

Therefore you'd need:

```
DirectoryIndex homepage.html
```

within the `VirtualHost`.

Comment: Works great, you just have to know it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First stop the service:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd stop
```

Open configuration file of apache

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Add

```
DirectoryIndex  homepage.html
```

Here you can add.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/vb1.be
    ServerName vb1.be
    ServerAlias www.vb1.be
    ErrorLog logs/vb1.be-error_log
    DirectoryIndex  homepage.html
    CustomLog logs/vb1.be-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Check if there is any error in syntax using

```
httpd -t
```

start httpd

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```